# Tailing a collection before it is created

Tags: python, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pymongo

I'm developing an application where data is inserted into a `capped` collection via `mongoose` in Node.js and is tailed by `pymongo` in a Python program. I'm having a small issue where `mongoose` doesn't create the collection until a document is inserted into it.

In Node.js I attempt to create the collection like so:

```
var MyModel = mongoose.model('mymodel', mymodelSchema);
```

In my `pymongo` program I want to tail `MyModel` so I do this:

```
mymodels = db.mymodels.find(cursor_type=CursorType.TAILABLE_AWAIT)
```

The issue here is that if this line is called *before* a single entry is inserted into the `mymodels` collection nothing happens when I do this:

```
for model in mymodels:
    # nothing happens
```

I want to start my Python program to watch for new documents - before the Node.js server starts accepting new documents. However, until a single document is inserted, the Python program won't work.

Comment: If the collection is meant to be "capped" then MongoDB would actually create the collection first "regardless" of whether anything is inserted or not. It's a requirement of "capped" collections that you call a `.createCollection()`. So this actually has nothing to do with your mongoose application at all. Or at least you are not adequately explaining any timing issue that you think exists. Or in fact it's another problem.

Comment: @NeilLunn thank you for the reply. Please see my edit. I don't call `.createCollection()` I'm not sure where to

Comment: Well if that is not actually called anywhere the it is **not** a ["capped collection"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/) and would just be a normal collection. So what's the real issue here? How to keep polling for a collection to create being creating the tailable cursor? Would it not just be more simple case to rather just make sure the collection is created in your deployment?

Comment: I believe `mongoose` automatically creates the collection when the first document is inserted. I want to find out how to create the collection before this happens. The issue is that `mymodels` doesn't work when called *before* the first documented is inserted because the collection `mymodels` hasn't been created yet.

Comment: Please go back and read what I just said. You a missing the two plain and obvious points. 1. Not a capped collection. 2. Don't wait for something to create, but just deploy the application that way. Don't make things difficult for yourself. Just do the simple things, and problem solved.

Comment: @NeilLunn sorry for not making this clear. I'm not waiting for the collection to get created. `mongoose` doesn't create the collection until a document is inserted.