# MongoError: No More Documents in Tailed Cursor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a capped collection that I'm trying to tail using `mongoose`. The tailable stream errors out when all documents are exhausted or if there are none at all.

mongoose schema

```
var photoSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    operations: Schema.Types.Mixed,
}, {
    capped: {
        size: 300 * 500,
        max: 500,
        autoIndexId: true
    }
});
```

implementation

```
var RawPhoto = mongoose.model('RawPhoto', photoSchema);
var ProcessedPhoto = mongoose.model('ProcessedPhoto', photoSchema)

var ProcessedPhoto = mongoose.model('ProcessedPhoto', photoSchema)

var processedPhotoStream = ProcessedPhoto.find().tailable(true, 
    {awaitdata: true, numberOfRetries: Number.MAX_VALUE}).stream();

processedPhotoStream.on('data', function(photo){
    console.log(photo.name);
}).on('error', function(error){
    console.error(error);
}).on('close', function(){
    console.log("processed photo stream closed")
});
```

In my console I get a `MongoError: No more documents in tailed cursor` and my own message `processed photo stream closed`. I saw that people were having trouble with this in the past due to an incompatibility between mongoose and the latest version of MongoDB, but I am still having this issue.

Comment: Is this actually a "capped collection"? On your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36687627/tailing-a-collection-before-it-is-created) there was no reason to believe it was in fact a "capped collection" since you admitted not creating it as such. I'm really struggling to see how these are different questions, as both are solved by simply creating the "capped collection".

Comment: @NeilLunn yes I have defined it as a capped collection in my mongoose schema. mongoose creates the collection automatically

Comment: I don't believe you. You would not be getting the error if you did. Show the code where you are creating the "capped collection".

Comment: @NeilLunn please see edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cursor flags are incorrect and are therefore ignored. You really only want `awaitData` with a "capital 'D'":

```
var processedPhotoStream = ProcessedPhoto.find().tailable(true, 
    { awaitData: true }).stream();
```

The valid options are listed in the native driver documentation for [`addCursorFlag`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Cursor.html#addCursorFlag)

> The flag to set, must be one of following ['tailable', 'oplogReplay', 'noCursorTimeout', 'awaitData', 'partial'].

---

### Simple listing with no Problems

```
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/capped');
mongoose.set('debug',true);

var photoSchema = new Schema({
  "name": String
}, {
  "capped" : {
    "size": 500 * 1024,
    "max": 500
  }
});

var Photo = mongoose.model('Photo',photoSchema);

var stream = Photo.find().tailable(true,
  { awaitData: true }).stream();

stream.on('data',function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
stream.on('err',function(err) {
  console.error(err);
});
stream.on('close',function() {
  console.log('done');
});

setInterval(function() {
  Photo.create({ "name": "Ted" },function(err,photo) {

  });
},2000);
```

**The output that keeps on giving:**

```
Mongoose: photos.find({}) { awaitData: true, tailable: true, fields: undefined }
Mongoose: photos.insert({ name: 'Ted', _id: ObjectId("5715af20daa62598059adaf1"), __v: 0 })
{ __v: 0, name: 'Ted', _id: 5715af20daa62598059adaf1 }
Mongoose: photos.insert({ name: 'Ted', _id: ObjectId("5715af23daa62598059adaf2"), __v: 0 })
{ __v: 0, name: 'Ted', _id: 5715af23daa62598059adaf2 }
Mongoose: photos.insert({ name: 'Ted', _id: ObjectId("5715af25daa62598059adaf3"), __v: 0 })
{ __v: 0, name: 'Ted', _id: 5715af25daa62598059adaf3 }
```

Comment: Thanks but I still get the same error after removing all other options but awaitData spelled correctly

Comment: @Carpetfizz Works perfectly for me. Make sure the collection actually is "capped" like I have been saying all along. The `.stats()` method in the shell will tell you. If in doubt, then drop the collection and turn on mongoose debugging `mongoose.set("debug",1)` to see that the capped collection is being created properly. If not, then update mongoose and/or just create the "capped collection" in the database directly. My little small listing works every time. Want to see?

Comment: thanks again, I'll look through your example and see if I missed anything.

Comment: Hm what version of monngoose and mongodb are you using? I copied the exact same thing and it's not working. I'm using the latest of both

Comment: @Carpetfizz Copied into what? A blank directory? Don't just run the code in your existing project folder, as you could possibly have conflicting dependencies in there. The build was done against a latest mongoose release, but it really should not matter that much. The actual MongoDB version should not matter at all. I suggest you do the same and run this in it's own folder with clean dependencies. Then gradually step down mongoose until you see a problem. In a similar manner, include your project dependencies until you see a problem.

Comment: @Carpetfizz This is actually really what [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is all about.

Comment: I copied this code into a new folder, only installed mongoose, and ran it. I got the same exact error.

Comment: @Carpetfizz Sounds like you have other problems on your end. The practical thing here is that this **is** the correct way to do it. You appear to have other environment problems that you really need to resolve, and are outside of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when i created a tailable cursor on a collection that didnt exist. In my case i created a collection 'capped' but mongoose adds the 's' at the end of model names. Because collections become plural the tailed cursor was looking for collection name 'cappeds'